# Independence of increments of Wiener processes

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a Wiener process.
In the demonstration provided below (which is right), it is said, knowing $s<t$, that $W_s$ and $W_t - W_s$ are independent because increments of Wiener processes are independent.

My question is : as $W_s$ and $W_t$ can be considered respectively as $W_s-W_0$ and $W_t-W_0$ (as $W_0=0$), why can't we use the same argument (that they are independent because increments of Wiener processes are independent) and say that they are uncorrelated.

---

Here is the computation of the covariance of $W_s$ and $W_t$ where $W_t$ is a Wiener process in which we use this property.

The covariance between $W_s$ and $W_t$ is given by:

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = \mathbb{E}[(W_s - \mathbb{E}[W_s])(W_t - \mathbb{E}[W_t])]$

Since Wiener processes have mean zero at all points, $\mathbb{E}[W_s] = \mathbb{E}[W_t] = 0$, and this simplifies to:

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = \mathbb{E}[W_s W_t]$

Now, let's consider the joint distribution of $W_s$ and $W_t$. Since Wiener processes have independent and normally distributed increments, we have:

$W_t - W_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t - s)$

Now, let's express $W_t$ in terms of $W_s$ and the increment $W_t - W_s$:

$W_t = W_s + (W_t - W_s)$

Now, we can write the covariance:

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = \mathbb{E}[W_s(W_s + (W_t - W_s))]$

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = \mathbb{E}[W_s^2 + W_s(W_t - W_s)]$

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = \mathbb{E}[W_s^2] + \mathbb{E}[W_s(W_t - W_s)]$

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = s + \mathbb{E}[W_s(W_t - W_s)]$

Now, $W_s$ and $W_t - W_s$ are independent because increments of Wiener processes are independent, so the expectation of their product is the product of their expectations:

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = s + \mathbb{E}[W_s] \mathbb{E}[W_t - W_s]$

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = s + 0$

Therefore, we have:

$\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = s$

This is the same result as: $\text{Cov}(W_s, W_t) = min(s, t)$, but for $(s < t)$.

Comment: The correct statement is that increments of the Wiener process on **non-overlapping** intervals are independent.

Comment: W$\color{red}{\text{ie}}\,$ner please.

Comment: Thank you noticing, I corrected it! @KurtG.

Comment: Thanks. Has @RobertIsrael's comment answered your main question?

Comment: While we're correcting spelling, it's independence, not independance.

Comment: Thanks @RobertIsrael